# How to create an n x n system of equations using the system environment?

Tags: equations, systeme

I am trying to write a system of equations, I usually do it with the align environments but while I was researching the community, I saw that there was the systeme package and it seemed interesting to use it to create systems of equations, and I want the terms to be nicely spaced as the image below. I have reviewed several posts about the **systeme package** but the results I get are not the desired ones.

[image]

Here is the code that I was testing but I have complications when adding the i-th and n-th rows.

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:sys_lin}
\syssubstitute{{w_3}{\sysdots}{w_4}{w_n}}
\systeme*{
  b_1=a_{11}x_1 + a_{21}x_2 + \dots + a_{1n}x_n,
  b_2=a_{21}x_1 + a_{22}x_2 + \dots + a_{2n}x_n,
  \vdots + \vdots + + \vdots , b_i=a_{i1} + a_{i2} + \dots + a_{in},\vdots + \vdots + + \vdots,b_n=a_{n1}x_1 + a_{n2}x_2 + \dots + a_{nn}x_n
}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that `systeme` would easily accommodate that display. It's very good for *explicit* systems, but placing dots like in the example isn't easy (if at all possible). On the other hand you're not going to use such a display many times, so a more difficult code once is not too bad.

You can use `nicematrix` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{NiceArray}{ l @{\quad} *{4}{r >{{}}c<{{}}} c }
\mathbf{L}_1 & a_{11}x_1 &+& a_{12}x_2 &+& \cdots &+& a_{1n}x_n &=& c_1 \\[1ex]
\mathbf{L}_2 & a_{21}x_1 &+& a_{22}x_2 &+& \cdots &+& a_{2n}x_n &=& c_2 \\
\multicolumn{1}{c@{\quad}}{\vdots} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\vdots} &&
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\vdots} &&
  &&
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\vdots} &&
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\vdots} \\[0.5ex]
\mathbf{L}_i & a_{i1}x_1 &+& a_{i2}x_2 &+& \cdots &+& a_{in}x_n &=& c_i \\
\multicolumn{1}{c@{\quad}}{\vdots} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\vdots} &&
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\vdots} &&
  &&
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\vdots} &&
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\vdots} \\[0.5ex]
\mathbf{L}_n & a_{n1}x_1 &+& a_{n2}x_2 &+& \cdots &+& a_{nn}x_n &=& c_n
\CodeAfter\SubMatrix\{{1-2}{6-2}.
\end{NiceArray}
\]

\end{document}
```

You need to compile a few times for the warning to disappear when you add or modify a `NiceArray`.

[image]

Please, note that `\mathbf{L_i}` is wrong, because a boldface “i” has no connection with an italic one.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that the machinery of the `systeme` package is well suited for the task at hand. Instead, I'd use two side-by-side `array` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{array}      % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}} % for binary and relational operators
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional (Times Roman clones)

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}      % default value: 5pt
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}  % default value: 1.0
\begin{array}{ c } % single-column array
\mathbf{L}_1 \\ \mathbf{L}_2 \\ \vdots \\ \mathbf{L}_i \\ \vdots \\ \mathbf{L}_n
\end{array}
\quad
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{ *{4}{cC}c } % array with 9 (logical) columns
a_{11}x_1 &+& a_{12}x_2 &+& \cdots &+& a_{1n}x_n &=& c_1    \\
a_{21}x_1 &+& a_{22}x_2 &+& \cdots &+& a_{2n}x_n &=& c_2    \\
\vdots    & & \vdots    & &        & & \vdots    & & \vdots \\
a_{i1}x_1 &+& a_{i2}x_2 &+& \cdots &+& a_{in}x_n &=& c_i    \\
\vdots    & & \vdots    & &        & & \vdots    & & \vdots \\
a_{n1}x_1 &+& a_{n2}x_2 &+& \cdots &+& a_{nn}x_n &=& c_n
\end{array} 
\right.
\]

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*, posted after @egreg posted a separate answer: I've removed the bold-facing of the subscripts to `\mathbf{L}`, as I agree that it's preferable to write `\mathbf{L}_i` rather than `\mathbf{L_i}`, etc.